# htaccess redirect with unique id to title

Tags: .htaccess

I have URL's like this:

```
http://www.example.com/en/product.php?id=23&t=page-title-here
```

I want change URL's to something like this :

```
http://www.example.com/en/product23/page-title-here/
```

Comment: Where does "page-title-here" come from? Made up, not important?

Comment: That's right, I forgot the title. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following in your `/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Step 1: Redirect file-based URIs to new 'pretty permalinks' and prevent looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&t=([^/]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(en/product).php$ /$1%1/%2? [R=302,NE,L]

# Step 2: Rewrite above permalink to file-based URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(en/product)(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?id=$2&t=$3 [L,QSA]
```

**Update:** If you want to match multiple languages (per your comment below), you can use a non-capture group that checks for exactly two characters instead of just `en`:

```
# Use this rule in step 1 above
RewriteRule ^((?:[a-z]{2})/product).php$ /$1%1/%2? [R=302,NE,L]
```

```
# Use this rule in step 2 above
RewriteRule ^((?:[a-z]{2})/product)(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?id=$2&t=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: sorry, i have another question. this code will only affect the /en/ directory. For the rest of the directories, i should repeat the code. is possible The above code work in all directories ? like /sp/ , /fa/ and others ...

Comment: It's Work!! thanks a lot. what about for this code ?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} en/product([0-9]+)/([^/]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/product.php?id=%1&t=%2

Comment: @Mohammad - I believe I've answered your initial question, and your second question. If you need more help, please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).